# is there way to create white dot using code that shows progress of onboarding?

Tags: java, android, mobile-application

As you can see in this link(http://amyjokim.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Duolingo-Onboarding-3.jpg)

AT the bottom of picture, There are dots to show the progress of onboarding. is there way to create white dot using code that shows progress of onboarding? What is the best way to create them? using image?

is there way to create white dot using code that shows progress of onboarding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those are called `ViewPagerIndicator`.

[This library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) provide options for a lot of shapes and sizes in viewpager indicator with [sample application](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/tree/master/sample).

> Include one of the widgets in your view. This should usually be placed
>   adjacent to the ViewPager it represents.
>
> ```
> <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
>     android:id="@+id/titles"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
> ```
>
> In your onCreate method (or onCreateView for a fragment), bind the
>   indicator to the ViewPager.
>
> ```
> //Set the pager with an adapter
>  ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
>  pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
>
>  //Bind the title indicator to the adapter
>  TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);
>  titleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
> ```
>
> (Optional) If you use an OnPageChangeListener with your view pager you
>   should set it in the indicator rather than on the pager directly.
>
> ```
>  //continued from above
>  titleIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

try this code. Create a xml in drawables copy below code. If you want different colors changes ffffff to your_color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <size
            android:width="8dp"
            android:height="8dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: I will try it. Thank you!